# CSS hide elements when they aren't in the parent

Tags: jquery, css, parent

I have used jQuery and CSS to create a cool effect, where arrows fly across the screen inside of a large triangle. The problem is that I only want the moving arrows to be visible when they are inside the triangle. Even if one pixel of the arrow is inside the triangle, that part should become visible.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/A4dc7/

**CSS:**

```
.arrow_first {
    position: absolute;
    top: -108px;
    left: -142px;
    border-left: 44px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 60px solid white;
    z-index: 10;
}
.arrow_second {
    position: absolute;
    top: -229px;
    left: -213px;
    border-left: 26px solid transparent;
    border-right: 14px solid transparent;
    border-top: 40px solid white;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 7;
}
.arrow_third {
    position: absolute;
    top: -280px;
    left: -202px;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 12px solid white;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 5;
}
.arrow_fourth {
    position: absolute;
    top: -116px;
    left: -111px;
    border-left: 21px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top: 28px solid white;
    z-index: 10;
}
.arrow_five {
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    left: -173px;
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 21px solid white;
    z-index: 8;
}
.arrow_six {
    position: absolute;
    top: -294px;
    left: -257px;
    border-left: 31px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 42px solid white;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

I think it should be done with `$.parent` on jQuery, but I don't know how to id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work the way you want.
Usually, to make sure a child element is contained visually by the parent, you need to set `overflow:hidden;` to the parent element.
In your case you use `height:0; width:0;` for your parent and you just have borders to depict your element... no dice with that one AFAIK, cause setting overflow to hidden on an 0x0 px parent -  will not make visible your child elements.

Comment: so what should I use instead of `border:` to paint triangle? and keep width and height to the triangle position

Comment: @baitas212123 I don't think it's doable. I know only for that 0x0 trick. I would go for an animated .gif, at least would work crossBrowser

Comment: @baitas212123 A solution actually could be using **SVG**. Find out on Goog how to do it.